# Is there a customizable Memrise-like spaced-repetition software that lets the user choose an answer from a list?

Tags: vocabulary, anki, spaced-repetition, software, memrise

I use both [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) and [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com/) to learn vocabulary but these days I'm getting to think that Anki is not that effective to learn a word, as it is just flipping a card. On the other hand, Memrise lets you learn a word by typing in the word or choosing the word from a list of 4 up to 8 cards, but it is difficult to create your own card since the customizability is not as extensive as Anki and also you can't create a card on mobile.

So I'm looking for a way of learning by choosing a correct word by a list of words. I would like to know an answer either by installing 3rd-party Anki plugins (if any) or another SRS program.

Is there such plugin or program?

---

By 'Memrise-like SRS', I meant any solution where the screen shows a list of words that include 1 correct answer mixed with 3 to 7 wrong answers, where the wrong answers are automatically chosen from other cards on the deck. In other words, the list of answers is created dynamically when you move to a new screen, which is different from the plugin on which a user sets the list of words manually when creating the card.

[image]

Comment: There's no point in memorizing loose words. You need to learn them in context, like in a dialogue.

Comment: Memrise no longer allows customizable courses, even on their web portal.

Answer (score 0):

Note added 2020-12-28. Original answer given 2020-12-26. In the light of new information added by the question poster, it is clear that the answer I have given here does not solver the poster's problem. Nonetheless, I have not deleted the answer because it might provide useful information to someone with a slightly different problem!

---

I have used Anki extensively but have no knowledge of Memrise so my answer might be based on misconceptions about exactly what you want.

You say, "Memrise lets you learn a word by typing in the word or choosing the word from a list of 4 up to 8 cards". It isn't clear whether you're saying that (i) at each "turn", Memrise gives you a choice of 4 to 8 cards from which you then select the one you would like to learn, or (ii) Memrise presents you with a single test questions/words on each occasion but also shows you between 4 and 8 possible answers/translations.

I assume from the title line of your question that you actually mean the second of the options in which case I'd make the following observations. There seem to be two things you want. First, it sounds as if the style of question-and-answer you are looking for is similar to that of a multiple choice exam where the correct answer is mixed in with several incorrect answers. The second aspect that you seem to be asking about is whether it is possible to type in answers, rather then merely mentally deciding on the answer and then checking it.

If I have interpreted your question correctly, then might you try out [each](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1280092568) [of](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1566095810) the [four](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/413154037) [different](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/843236755) multiple-choice plugins for [Anki](https://ankiweb.net/shared/addons/). An alternative might be to construct the front of the Anki card so you list the multiple-choice answers yourself, and then make use of the [type-in-the-answer](https://docs.ankidroid.org/#typeInAnswer) feature (which I gathered you were unaware of). If you choose this approach, you might find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Schl0ZozIN4) helpful.

Comment: You are correct that it is (ii). I didn't intend to get answers regarding type-in-the-answer, one of the plugins of which I tried in the past but found to be pretty useless. As to the multiple choice questions I meant it should be a plugin that creates automatically a list of choice based on the other cards on the deck, not by creating those cards manually. I'll edit my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own via MS Access.   Fully customizable.  This video is the one I used to create it:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UX0FxXVGwjY&t=972s&ab_channel=ComputerLearningZone

Based on the button I clicked, I have the database re-presenting vocabulary words based on if I clicked "I got it wrong", "I got it right - but barely" and "I got it right - Easy".   I have it retesting me on words based on which I clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Memrise and create your own course. But this needs to be done in their web portal. You can only use mobile app to start the course and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Anki certainly allows one to answer a card by typing in a response. In Anki, the kind of response is referred to as a cloze. You might like to have a look at [this](https://www.ollielovell.com/edtech/anki3/) discussion. In addition, there are a variety of add-ons that enable one to [create lists](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1280092568).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is the droid you are looking for?

Free & open source software framework & a large library of quiz question types: https://h5p.org/ If you're techy, this is all you'll need.

Less techy commercial service option: https://h5p.com/

Here's a free desktop app for creating & editing H5P quizzes: https://lumi.education/

Warning: This software is designed for use & integration with Learning Management Systems (LMS') at schools, colleges, universities, & corporations. As such, it doesn't do the things that LMS' usually do, e.g. keeping scores, & scheduling & sequencing learning sessions. However, Moodle does come with H5P included as standard & you can easily install it for free on your computer (Windows & Mac): https://download.moodle.org/releases/latest/ However, Moodle's a full-blown LMS & takes time & effort to learn how to use. Maybe not the easiest, quickest route if you just want to make & practise a few multiple choice quizzes.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer looks like spam.

Comment: Spam? The original question is asking for recommendations of software. I recommended one, including caveats as to why it may not be suitable in some cases.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing to highlight how this (paid) software relates to the language learning and SRS.  As it stands, it looks like links to random webpages.

Comment: I'm assuming you're the one who's down modded a helpful comment?
Both H5P & Moodle are community driven, non-profit, free & open source software projects used by schools, colleges, & universities. Again, the original question asked for recommendations for software for particular functions, i.e. flashards & multiple choice questions, which this software does. What more can I say?